# complex math exercise on python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

this is the task I get:
Complex numbers can be represented on a two-dimensional space. Consider complex numbers  cc  of the form  c=x+1j*y (j is the imaginary unit), where  x∈[−2,0.5] and  y∈[−1,1]. Imagine to have a two-dimensional grid in this space, with each step of the grid being  10ˆ(-2) . For each  c corresponding to one of the nodes of the grid, calculate the iterative function  `Z_{n+1} = Zˆ2_n + c`, with  n∈[1,100] and  Z_0=0 . Plot the grid by coloring with black the cell corresponding to  c  if  Z_n  diverges (i.e.  |Z_n| is a NaN, otherwise color it with white.

Since I am not a math student, I am in trouble with that. So far, I could do till this point:

```
import numpy as np

x_values = np.arange(-2, 0.5, 0.01)
y_values = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01)
M = np.zeros((len(x_values), (len(y_values))), dtype = "complex")

for x in range(len(x_values)): 
    for y in range(len(y_values)): 
        M[x][y] = x_values[x] +1j*y_values[y]
```

could you tell me how I can define a function that takes a grid/array like the one we have, initializes z=0 and then 100 times (i.e. for n in range(100)) does:  z = z**2 + grid
then after the loop return z.
then to plot the image:

Comment: All of your equations seemed to have been pasted twice, rendering them unreadable.  Please adjust and reformat.

Comment: It sounds like your task is to implement a Mandelbrot set (or maybe a Julia set) calculator.

Comment: adjusted the question as much as can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there!

Just add a little bit more to your `for`-loops:

```
for x in range(len(x_values)): 
    for y in range(len(y_values)): 
        for i in range(100):
            M[x][y] = M[x][y]**2 + (x_values[x] + 1j*y_values[y])
```

(I don't have numpy available at the moment, so I couldn't test it, but it's not too complicated so it's probably fine.)

As for the plotting, I suggest checking out [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/). If you have trouble, ask another SO question. But until you've tried something, I don't want to just write the whole thing for you. ;)

Comment: def apply_function(matrix):
z=0
for n in range(100):
    z = z**2 + matrix
return z

Comment: what about this one? ))

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Can you say that again a little more precisely please?